# Fuel Java sdk subexpression is not appearing to work

Tags: java, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

Attempting to use the java fuel sdk to pull data from a data extension table.  In that table there is a date column which I am trying to create a filter with expression to get rows between two dates.  I have tried the between operator with a bunch of shotgun approaches to the value with no luck.  I then tried to use the subexpression with one expression being the greater than date and a subexpression added to it for the less than date.  I have also tried one parent expression with just two subexpressions for the greater and less than date with no luck too.

Does anyone know how to use the java sdk to retrieve rows between two dates?  Or know how the subexpression is suppose to be used/composed?

Thanks
Eric

Comment: Are you connecting ETClient successfully? Is that using clientId/clientSecret or username/password?

Comment: Yes I can connect successfully and I am using a client id and client secret.  It will even pull back data from my extension.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
        ETFilter filter = new ETFilter();
        filter.setExpression(ETExpression.parse(fromDate + " <= yourDate " + " and " + "yourDate <=" + toDate));
        result = extension.select(filter);
```